# Cannot use bindings for additional Y-axis in Telerik

Tags: c#, wpf, telerik

I'm using the RadChart from Telerik in WPF and I have a problem when I want to specify the MaxValue, MinValue and Step for an additional Y-axis.

It works fine if I hardcode the values like this (the relevant part is the last four lines):

```
<Controls:AxisY MinorTicksVisibility="Hidden" 
    DefaultLabelFormat="#VAL{#,##0}" 
    Title="{UI:Language @{xCubicMetrePerHourSymbol}}" 
    MajorGridLinesVisibility="Hidden" StripLinesVisibility="Visible" 
    AxisName="CubicMetreAxis" 
    AutoRange="False" 
    MaxValue="10000" 
    MinValue="0" 
    Step="0">
```

But since I want to change the MinValue, MaxValue and Step depending on the values in the series, I have to bind it this way using properties from a ViewModel object (which is supposed to be my inherited DataContext):

```
<Controls:AxisY MinorTicksVisibility="Hidden" 
    DefaultLabelFormat="#VAL{#,##0}" 
    Title="{UI:Language @{xCubicMetrePerHourSymbol}}" 
    MajorGridLinesVisibility="Hidden" StripLinesVisibility="Visible" 
    AxisName="CubicMetreAxis" 
    AutoRange="False" 
    MaxValue="{Binding Path=MyMaxValue}" 
    MinValue="{Binding Path=MyMinValue}"
    Step="{Binding Path=MyStep}">
```

But it seems that the DataContext cannot be seen / set from the additional Y-axis from what I've gathered using Snoop.

I get the following error message (the same message for each of the bindings):

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 2 : Cannot find governing FrameworkElement or 
FrameworkContentElement for target element. BindingExpression:Path=MyMaxValue;   
DataItem=null; target element is 'AxisY' (HashCode=47300984); target property is 
'MaxValue' (type 'Double')
```

I thought I had made a mistake somewhere and have searched for hours, but I discovered something weird: if I use those bindings in the "original" Y-axis, everything works perfectly. The code is exactly the same for both axes. The only difference is in the parent elements.

This works:

```
<Controls:ChartArea.AxisY>
    <Controls:AxisY MinorTicksVisibility="Hidden" 
                    DefaultLabelFormat="#VAL{#,##0}" 
                    Title="{UI:Language @{GigaJoulePerHourSymbol}}" 
                    MajorGridLinesVisibility="Hidden" 
                    StripLinesVisibility="Visible" 
                    AutoRange="False" 
                    MaxValue="{Binding Path=MyMaxValue}" 
                    MinValue="{Binding Path=MyMinValue}" 
                    Step="{Binding Path=MyStep}">
        <Controls:AxisY.AxisStyles>
            <Controls:AxisStyles TitleStyle="{StaticResource TranslatedAxisStyle}" />
        </Controls:AxisY.AxisStyles>
    </Controls:AxisY>
</Controls:ChartArea.AxisY>
```

This doesn't:

```
<Controls:ChartArea.AdditionalYAxes>
    <Controls:AxisY MinorTicksVisibility="Hidden" 
                    DefaultLabelFormat="#VAL{#,##0}" 
                    Title="{UI:Language @{xCubicMetrePerHourSymbol}}" 
                    MajorGridLinesVisibility="Hidden" 
                    StripLinesVisibility="Visible"
                    AxisName="CubicMetrePerHourAxis"  
                    AutoRange="False" 
                    MaxValue="{Binding Path=MyMaxValue}" 
                    MinValue="{Binding Path=MyMinValue}" 
                    Step="{Binding Path=MyStep}">
        <Controls:AxisY.AxisStyles>
            <Controls:AxisStyles TitleStyle="{StaticResource TranslatedAxisStyle}" />
        </Controls:AxisY.AxisStyles>
    </Controls:AxisY>
</Controls:ChartArea.AdditionalYAxes>
```

The element itself is exactly the same, except that the second one has a name and the title is different, but I tested and it doesn't actually affect anything. The only difference is that the parent elements are different.

I'd like to know why the *AxisY* sees the DataContext and can bind properly while the *AdditionalYAxis* cannot.

Comment: Probably (I'm guessing) because `AdditionalYAxes` is not in the visual tree.  See if you can apply one of the standard workarounds, eg: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5647426/1001985

Comment: @McGarnagle It works! Thanks a lot, I would never have found out how to do it. Post this as an answer if you want me to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `AdditionalYAxis` is presumably not in the [visual tree](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753391%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#two_trees), it will not inherit its logical-tree parent's `DataContext`.  That explains why binding is not working in the normal way.  You can use a workaround like the one outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5647426/1001985) ("data context spy") to get the binding working correctly.