# Binding to properties in both the ViewModel and CodeBehind

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, binding

I have what I'm sure is a ridiculously ignorant question, but I'm asking it anyways because I've searched and searched and either don't understand the solutions I'm seeing or not finding exactly the answer I seek.

I have an MVVM application.  My XAML is setup with the DataContext set to the VM where the data items on the screen are populated from the VM's properties.  My CodeBehind doesn't fiddle with the data, only things relating to the screen.

What I want to do now is bind certain UI elements to properties in the foo.xaml.cs (CodeBehind) file.  For example, I want to specify FontSize's bound to properties in the CB so that in the WindowInitialized handler in the CB, it can detect screen sizes and change one variable to which all the screen items' FontSize= are bound.

I can solve this the wrong way by creating a public property in my VM and then "inject" the value from the CB into the VM.  I know that will work, but it's a roundabout way to get the behavior I want, it's not at all straightforward, and I feel confident it's the wrong way to proceed.

I searched around and have tried things like:

```
    FontSize="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self},Path="MyFontSize"
```

(where "MyFontSize" is a public int property) and a variety of other examples I found, but none have worked.

So specifically, if my CodeBehind class is called **NameChangeSetupMainWindow** and that's where the "MyFontSize" property lives,

```
public partial class NameChangeSetupMainWindow : Window
{
    private int m_fontSize = 14;
    public int MyFontSize
    {
        get { return m_fontSize; }
        set
        {
            if (m_fontSize != value))
            {
                m_fontSize = (value > 0) ? value : 10;
            }
        }
    }
    ...
    ... rest of the class...
    ...
}
```

and the VM is called **NameChangeSetupViewModel** and that's where the "real" data lives and the DataContext points ala:

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <local:NameChangeSetupViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>
```

what is the syntax in XAML to bind just those UI items (tooltips related to the UI, font sizes, etc) to variables in the CodeBehind instead of housing them in the VM?

Thanks in advance for any guidance you can supply.

Comment: `{RelativeSource Self}` will only work for the `Window`. Where did you apply this binding? Btw, you could also change the fontsize of UI elements directly in code behind, without using binding.

Comment: Yes, thanks, HighCore, I am considering that, but I thought it would be worthwhile to point a number of UI-specific things, such as FontSize and styles and such, to a centralized variable.

Comment: Oh, and for the "Where did you apply this binding?" I tried it in the XAML file inside of the "<Window" tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`RelativeSource AncestorType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.relativesource.ancestortype%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to bind to properties of the view itself:

```
<TextBlock FontSize="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window},Path=MyFontSize}" />
```

Using `ElementName` should work as well:

```
<Window x:Name="window">

    <TextBlock FontSize="{Binding ElementName=window,Path=MyFontSize}" />
</Window>
```

---

**Edit**

Here is an example that I've confirmed working:

**XAML**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfAbc.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
    ToolTip="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self},Path=MyToolTip}"
    >
    <Grid>
        <TextBlock Text="hello world" FontSize="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window},Path=MyFontSize}" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**Code Behind**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private int m_fontSize = 20;
    public int MyFontSize
    {
        get { return m_fontSize; }
        set
        {
            if (m_fontSize != value)
            {
                m_fontSize = (value > 0) ? value : 10;
            }
        }
    }

    public string MyToolTip
    {
        get { return "hello world"; }
    }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Articles on this topic:

- [The `RelativeSource` markup extension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743599%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
- [XAML binding declarations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752300%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Related background:

- ["Namescopes" in XAML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms746659%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (when binding to a source using "ElementName", the source element must be in the same namescope)
- [Visual tree vs logical tree in XAML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753391%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (elements not in the visual tree, like Popup and ContextMenu, do not inherit DataContext.  Binding from these elements requires a workaround like the ["data context spy"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5647426/1001985) technique.)

Comment: I tried this verbatim, but it didn't work.  I'll try again by changing "window" to "NameChangeSetupMainWindow" because I suspect that's what you meant in shortcut form (I'm still pretty neophyte on the syntax/semantics of binding)

Comment: Well, maybe not...that generated an error of: "member names cannot be the same as their enclosing type" with the line number of this statement: 

        x:Name="NameChangeSetupMainWindow"

Comment: I tried both of the above examples, but neither worked.  Rather than the FontSize, I tried setting the "ToolTip" in the Window as in the following where ToolTip is a public string property in the CB file, but no go:
`
     <Window      
       ToolTip="{Binding  RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window},Path=ToolTip}"
`

Comment: @John hm, is the binding inside an outside-the-visual-tree element (popup, context menu), or inside a data template? That's the only reason I can think of, why the above would not work.

Comment: It's inside the <Window> tag.  I'm trying it with the ToolTip for the main window:  ToolTip="{Binding  RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window},Path=ToolTip}" -- the "ToolTip" property is a public string inside of the NameChangeSetupMainWindow:Window (the foo.xaml.cs file).

Comment: UPDATE: I had to rename "ToolTip" to "MyToolTip" due to a warning.  The property in the *.xaml.cs file is now public string MyToolTip and the XAML code is: ToolTip="{Binding  RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window},Path=MyToolTip}"

Comment: @John if it's on the Window itself, then you'll need `RelativeSource Self`... but wait, could it be the problem is just that you're not calling `RaisePropertyChanged` for the Font Size?

Comment: Not sure -- right now I'm trying it on the ToolTip of the main window. For grits and shins, I put a 'NotifyPropertyChanged("MyToolTip")' in the VM just to see if that would get the tooltip to show up when I mouse over the window, but it doesn't.  If I just put text into the ="Hello World!" of the ToolTip it shows up, but the binding acts as if there's no tooltip

Comment: @John that's weird.  Please see my edit above, a simplified example that works ...

Comment: That works! Thank you so much! Do you have a link to a good tutorial on binding, and/or a good reference page?  I'm delighted beyond words this is working, thanks to you, but a solution without a fundamental understanding of why it worked stops short of my objective.  Is it "Relative Self" because the XAML is essentially the same class as the CB, and thus "Self" is like a "this" reference?  I'm still fuzzy to this versus when to use "RelativeSource={Relative Source AncestorType=Window}..." etc...I really want to make sure I understand the construct.

In any event, thanks again!

Comment: @John yes, "Relative Self" is because XAML/CB is literally the same class (this is implemented "behind the scenes" using C# partial classes). As far as articles, I've always found MSDN to be good and thorough (and well organized, so it's easy to browse different topics). I added a few articles above that I found informative. Also, one crucial trick for debugging WPF bindings: watch the Output window in Visual Studio. If a binding fails, you will often see a helpful error message there.

Comment: Thank you -- I will re-peruse MSDN + the links you provided.

For those new to MVVM who might encounter my question and the answers above, binding the variables in the CB file did require that I add interface **INotifyPropertyChanged** and implement the necessary plumbing to fire the **NotifyPropertyChanged("MyToolTip")** events. While this is fundamental, if you're reading this question it's possible you might not know that. I'll leave the messy details out, but the signature now looks like this:

    `public partial class NameChangeSetupMainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged`