# Bind Stroke from the property in ItemSources

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding

I have a collection of the object say MyModel.cs. The collection is called `Some`. In MyModel it has a property Color which is Brush type.

The Color is Red for all now.

Now I have

```
<MyControl: x:Name="control1" ItemsSource="{Binding Some}" Stroke="Red">
```

But you see I hardcode the stroke. What I want is something like
     `Stroke = "{Binding Some.Color}"`

How?

Comment: You will need either use MultiBinding with custom converter (to resolve case when two models from collection has different colors - which to choose?) or move property to the upper level (where collection lives).

Comment: @Shcherban, if there are different colors then I have different collections. So I don't use MultiBinding.

Comment: Okay, then you can use just regular binding and pick color from first item in collection, like `Stroke={Binding Some, Converter=SomeConverter}` and in covnerter as simple as `return (value as IEnumerable<MyModel>)?.FirstOrDefault()?.Color ?? Colors.Red`

Comment: ok so you are looking something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5647426/2470362), as Shcherban mentioned Multibinding or move it to upper level are other options.

Comment: Does MyControl have a SelectedItem like a ListBox?

Comment: If MyControl has an ItemsSource property, it should also have an ItemTemplate. Declare a DataTemplate with an element that binds (e.g. its Background property) to Color.

Comment: Are you trying to set each item's Stroke separately, or are you trying to set one Stroke for the whole `MyControl`? There is a difference, it's an important difference. You *must* brace yourself, be very brave, and provide that information.

Comment: I am trying to set one Stroke for the whole MyControl@EdPlunkett

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The control displays *several* models. If you want to set the `Stroke` property to the `Color` of one of them, you need to specify which one, e.g.:

```
<MyControl x:Name="control1" ItemsSource="{Binding Some}" Stroke="{Binding Some[0].Color}">
```

This will bind the `Stroke` property to the `Color` property of the *first* `MyModel` object, assuming that the `Some` collection has an indexer.

Answer (score 1):

If `MyControl` inherits from `Selector`, set `IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"` and bind to `Some/Color`. The slash or virgule (`/`) means to use the `Color` property from the "current item" in the collection:

```
<MyControl 
    IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
    x:Name="control1" 
    ItemsSource="{Binding Some}" 
    Stroke="{Binding Some/Color}"
    />
```

This will use the selected item's Color brush for Stroke. You're quite understandably reluctant to provide any hints about what you're trying to do, but that's a fair guess.

If `MyControl` does not inherit from `Selector`, use mm8's solution.